# SEO URL best practice. How can I change my URL path?

Tags: magento2, seo

By looking at my magento product page I get this format:

https://mywebsite.com/catalog/product/view/id/18680/s/THIS-IS-THE-NAME-OF-MY-PRODUCT/category/17/

However, I don't think this is good for SEO. I want something like:

https://mywebsite.com/MY-CATEGORY-NAME/THIS-IS-THE-NAME-OF-MY-PRODUCT/

I also want this to be unique (even if a product is assigned to multiple category) to avoid duplicate content.

Did anyone achieve that yet?

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the below steps and update the configuration from the back end to follow SEO best practices as per your requirements.

**Step 1:**
In the Admin login go to path Stores > Configuration > Web.

**Step 2:**
After that, expand the Search Engine Optimization section.

**Step 3:**
Set Use Web Server Rewrites to ‘Yes’.

## **Set up automatic redirects:**

To set up automatic redirects we need to follow the steps given below:

**Step 1:**
In the Admin login go to path **Stores** > **Configuration** > **Catalog** > **Catalog**.

**Step 2:**
Expand the **Search Engine Optimization section**.
**Set Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed** to “Yes.”  and save the config value.

**Step 3:**
**Use Categories Path for Product URLs**: Yes [to make product URL unique even if a product is assigned to multiple categories)]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I still don't see the URL I want (https://mywebsite.com/MY-CATEGORY-NAME/THIS-IS-THE-NAME-OF-MY-PRODUCT/). Enabling Use Categories Path for Product URLs: Yes will make duplicate content if a product has more then one category.

Answer (score 0):

As you have performed @Pritam Solution & it didn't work. Try the below

**Enable Magento 2 Product URL Rewrite**

- Navigate to **CATALOG** -> **Products**
- Select the products that you want to change the URL of
- Expand the Search Engine Optimization menu Update the URL Key to the new one. Remember, only lowercase letters & characters are allowed
- Save the changes and Clear the Cache

**Enable Magento 2 Category URL Rewrite**

- Navigate to **CATALOG -> Category**
- Select the product that you want to change the URL
- Expand the Search Engine Optimization menu
- Update the URL Key to the new one. Remember, only lowercase letters & characters are allowed
- Save the changes and Clear the Cache

**Check Magento 2 URL Rewrite Record**

On the Admin Panel, navigate to **MARKETING -> URL Rewrites** under **SEO & Search** Section. It shows all the regenerated URL Rewrites with the most recent on the top.

**Remember to Re-Index from CLI using `php bin/magento indexer:reset && php bin/magento indexer:reindex` & Perform Cache Flush Once the above are done**

**For More Detailed Information** - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/catalog/catalog/catalog-urls.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, I have 17000 products and going one by one won't be possible.